# How to add "popup edit control"

Tags: mfc

I am working on an MFC aplication and i need to make following thing: Add a new popup edit control with three choises - "Red", "Green" and "Blue". I am working on VS 2005 and in the Toolbox i have only "Edit Control" to drop. How can i make the options of it so it became popup edit control and i can write my three choises? I know how to make it with ListBox but it is not the task description.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a combo box (CComboBox MFC class).